# UTC and Universal Time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In C#, what is the difference between UTC and Universal Time?
What are the functions available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think they're both the same - according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utc), UTC is `Coordinated *Universal* Time`.

.NET supports UTC through a number of function on the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) struct. E.g. there is  are functions like `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` (and `DateTime.ToLocalTime` to convert back, of course) or `DateTime.UtcNow` available.

Answer (score 2):

No difference.  DateTime.UtcNow gives you the current time in UTC.  The Timezone class has functions to convert to and from UTC date/time to date/time in any timezone.

Answer (score 0):

UTC = Universal Time.

You can convert your current local time to UTC by

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.UtcNow;
```

or convert a specified date/time by

```
TimeZoneInfo myTZInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");

// DateTime.SpecifyKind(Convert.ToDateTime("04:35 AM"), DateTimeKind.Unspecified), myTZInfo) tells whether you are conetring a local time or UTC, you can always leave it as unspecified

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(Convert.ToDateTime("2015-01-06 14:00:00.000"), DateTimeKind.Unspecified), myTZInfo).ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

you can get all time zone ids by==>

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo>  tzc= TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```